# Why does increment operator modify the original value and bit operators don't?

Tags: c

The increment operator modifies the original value like,

```
int i = 5;
i++;
printf("%d",i); //prints 6
```

but the bit operator does not, example,

```
int x = 5;
x<<1;
printf("%d",x);//should print 10 but outputs the original value i.e. 5
```

Comment: Because it's syntactic shorthand for `i = i + 1`. You can do something similar with `x <<= 1`.

Comment: It's the increment operator that's the odd one out.  None of the basic arithmetic operators modify their arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x << 1` is analogous to operations like `x * 2`. If you don't store the result anywhere, it is just discarded and the line may just get omitted entirely by an optimizing compiler.

If you want to store the result of an operation like that back into `x`, you have options like:

```
x = x * 2;
x *= 2;
```

The `<<` operator is the same:

```
x = x << 1;
x <<= 1;
```